# How to show only the last output line of a loop

Tags: java

First off I'm a total beginner at java,
I'm trying to do vigenere cipher
Without using File Reader.

This is my output:

```
program
Omgezet geeft dit: 
y
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yr
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrj
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrjg
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrjga
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrjgaa
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrjgaah
```

But I'm trying to get this output:

```
program
Omgezet geeft dit: 
yrjgaah
```

This is my code:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
            String tekst = sc.nextLine();
            String code = ""; //Variable om de code te laten werken.

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < tekst.length(); i++) {
                 char ch = tekst.charAt(i);
                 if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') continue; //Negeert nummers.
                 code += (char)((ch + sleutel.charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
                 j = ++j % sleutel.length();

            System.out.println("Omgezet geeft dit: ");
            System.out.println(code);
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
            String tekst = sc.nextLine();
            String code = ""; //Variable om de code te laten werken.

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < tekst.length(); i++) {
                 char ch = tekst.charAt(i);
                 if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') continue; //Negeert nummers.
                 code += (char)((ch + sleutel.charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
                 j = ++j % sleutel.length();
            }
        System.out.println("Omgezet geeft dit: ");
        System.out.println(code);

    }
```

Id est: putting the println sentences outside the loop.

Comment: Jezus.. lol ty very much. Didn't know u had only to change the brace.

Comment: @Paco what is difference b/w you answer and question?

Comment: The } mark (end of the loop). I have put it before the println sentences.

Comment: woops srry i'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

try printing it outside the loop

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < tekst.length(); i++) {
             char ch = tekst.charAt(i);
             if (ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') continue; //Negeert nummers.
             code += (char)((ch + sleutel.charAt(j) - 2 * 'a') % 26 + 'a');
             j = ++j % sleutel.length();                             
    }  

 System.out.println("Omgezet geeft dit: ");
 System.out.println(code);
```